# Prevent link fragment scrolling the page with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Im using a jQuery gallery. You can click on a thumbnail to make the image's larger version appear.

The issue is that the code uses link fragments. So when you click a thumbnail the page scrolls to large image which can feel very jerky.

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li>
    <a href="#imageID">
      <img src="myimage.jpg" />
    </a>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

I need to disable this browser scrolling behavior. Both of the methods in the js below do work but they also stop the jQuery gallery from working altogether, so when you click a thumbnail nothing happens. Is there a way to just disable this 1 bit of browser behavior?

```
        $(".widget a").click(function(e) {
        //  return false;   
        //  e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: `also stop the jQuery gallery from working altogether.` can't get it.

Comment: Ive updated by question.

Comment: Which gallery plugin? They usually handle this for you.